# Arch won't smooth

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh

I have previously fixed these kind of issues in other models but I can't in this case. How can I make the entire arch curve smoothly (which for some reason it doesn't even if I add subsurface) and then at the same time keep sharp edges?

[image]

Comment: if you subdivide, do it with the Subdivision Surface modifier instead of the right click Subdivide, but you can keep very lowpoly and give it a Subdivision Surface, in that case you only need some support edge loops around the edges that you want to keep sharp

Comment: Thank you for replying. Subdivision Surface modifier is already applied. I tried both Catmull Clark and Simple. It doesn't work. (I have used it many times before)

Comment: currently you have edge loops that will tend to flatten your shape, not round it, are you sure that you haven't used right click > Subdivide? Because if you do that without Smoothness it will only create additional edge loops without rounding the shape. Applying a new Subdivision Surface modifier won't help because of the current topology

Comment: Edit: oh ok it may be because you've applied the modifier with the Simple option enabled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you have this initial shape:

[image]

You have at least 3 solutions:

- If you apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier / *Catmull Clark*, here is what it gives, it works fine:

[image]

- If you apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier / *Simple*, here is what it gives, it won't work fine as it will create additional edges that won't respect the roundness, they will even tend to flatten the shape:

[image]

- If you right click > *Subdivide* the mesh, put the Smoothness value at 1 in the *Operator* box (otherwise it will give the same result as the *Subsurf Simple* option), here is what it gives, it's ok except it round the sides which you don't want:

[image]

So the best solution, if you don't want to keep any modifier, is probably to apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier / *Catmull Clark*.

That said, if you've already subdivided your mesh and did it incorrectly, meaning it has added edge loops that tend to flatten the mesh, and if you try to subdivide again, the new subdivision, whatever it is, won't be able to round the flattened mesh.

Comment: Thank you so much! I noticed that I had indeed applied the subdivision so I just "unsubdivided" and now it has rounded  out the arch. I can't remember how to keep sharp edges though. I'm pretty sure there war a way

Comment: to keep sharp edges, add edge loops close to the edges you want with Ctrl R